# How to handle hibernate UnsupportedOperationException "Can't write to a readonly object" with CacheConcurrencyStrategy setted NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE

Tags: java, hibernate, ehcache

I'm using hibernate second level cache implementation with EHCache.
The problem is that even though I have my Entity defined with CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE I was receiving the UnsupportedOperationException "Can't write to a readonly object".
Here is the stacktrace of the Exception:

```
 java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't write to a readonly object
    at org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.internal.strategy.ReadOnlyEhcacheEntityRegionAccessStrategy.update(ReadOnlyEhcacheEntityRegionAccessStrategy.java:115)
    at org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.internal.nonstop.NonstopAwareEntityRegionAccessStrategy.update(NonstopAwareEntityRegionAccessStrategy.java:216)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityUpdateAction.cacheUpdate(EntityUpdateAction.java:235)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:463)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:349)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:350)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1222)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:425)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:177)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:77)
    ... 53 more
javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:94)
    at com.asbitec.vbi.core.server.services.HibernateDBAccessHandler.commitTransaction(HibernateDBAccessHandler.java:40)
    at com.asbitec.vbi.framework.server.services.record.RecordHandler.executeProcess(RecordHandler.java:69)
    at com.asbitec.vbi.framework.server.services.record.RecordHandler.executeProcess(RecordHandler.java:1)
    at com.asbitec.vbi.framework.server.services.AbstractDispatcher.doExecute(AbstractDispatcher.java:23)
    at com.asbitec.vbi.framework.server.services.AbstractDispatcher.execute(AbstractDispatcher.java:15)
    at com.asbitec.vbi.framework.server.DispatcherServiceImpl.execute(DispatcherServiceImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor244.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:587)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:333)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:303)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:373)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:755)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.doServiceImpl(ServletDefinition.java:287)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.doService(ServletDefinition.java:277)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.service(ServletDefinition.java:182)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedServletPipeline.service(ManagedServletPipeline.java:91)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:85)
    at com.asbitec.vbi.framework.server.http.ExpiresFilter.doFilter(ExpiresFilter.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:82)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedFilterPipeline.dispatch(ManagedFilterPipeline.java:119)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter$1.call(GuiceFilter.java:133)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter$1.call(GuiceFilter.java:130)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter$Context.call(GuiceFilter.java:203)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter.doFilter(GuiceFilter.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1474)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:557)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:428)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.RequestLogHandler.handle(RequestLogHandler.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:489)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:960)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1021)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:865)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:240)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:668)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

And this is my Entity Definition:

```
@TypeDef(name="gasStationClassifier", defaultForType=GasStationClassifier.class, typeClass=com.asbitec.server.persistent.business.GasStationClassifierEnumType.class)
@Entity()
@Table(name="vGasolinera")
@Cache(usage=CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE, 
region="vbiEntityCache")
public class GasStation extends CatalogEntity {

    private Integer code;
    private String description;
    private String abbrev;
    private String company;
    private Integer companyCode;
    private String marketplace;
    private String region;
    private String field;
    private String externalCode;
    private GasStationClassifier classifier;
    private BigDecimal latitude;
    private BigDecimal longitude;
    private String brand;
    private String registerNumber;
    private String businessGroup;
    private String corporative;
    private String format;
    private String type;
    private Long version;

    @Column(name="Codigo")
    public Integer getCode() {
        return code;
    }
    public void setCode(Integer code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    @Column(name="Abreviatura")
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    @Column(name="Denominacion")
    public String getAbbrev() {
        return abbrev;
    }

    public void setAbbrev(String abbrev) {
        this.abbrev = abbrev;
    }

    @Column(name="Empresa")
    public String getCompany() {
        return company;
    }
    public void setCompany(String company) {
        this.company = company;
    }

    @Column(name="Mercado")
    public String getMarketplace() {
        return marketplace;
    }
    public void setMarketplace(String marketplace) {
        this.marketplace = marketplace;
    }

    @Column(name="Plaza")
    public String getRegion() {
        return region;
    }
    public void setRegion(String region) {
        this.region = region;
    }

    @Column(name="Campo")
    public String getField() {
        return field;
    }

    public void setField(String field) {
        this.field = field;
    }

    @Column(name="CodigoExterno")
    public String getExternalCode() {
        return externalCode;
    }
    public void setExternalCode(String externalCode) {
        this.externalCode = externalCode;
    }

    @Column(name="CodigoEmpresa")
    public Integer getCompanyCode() {
        return companyCode;
    }

    public void setCompanyCode(Integer companyCode) {
        this.companyCode = companyCode;
    }

    @Column(name="Clasificador")
    @Type(type="gasStationClassifier")
    public GasStationClassifier getClassifier() {
        return classifier;
    }

    public void setClassifier(GasStationClassifier classifier) {
        this.classifier = classifier;
    }

    @Column(name="Latitud")
    public BigDecimal getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }
    public void setLatitude(BigDecimal latitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }

    @Column(name="Longitud")
    public BigDecimal getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }
    public void setLongitude(BigDecimal longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

    @Column(name="Marca")
    public String getBrand() {
        return brand;
    }
    public void setBrand(String brand) {
        this.brand = brand;
    }

    @Column(name="NumeroCertificado")
    public String getRegisterNumber() {
        return registerNumber;
    }
    public void setRegisterNumber(String registerNumber) {
        this.registerNumber = registerNumber;
    }

    @Column(name="GrupoEconomico")
    public String getBusinessGroup() {
        return businessGroup;
    }
    public void setBusinessGroup(String businessGroup) {
        this.businessGroup = businessGroup;
    }

    @Column(name="Corporativo")
    public String getCorporative() {
        return corporative;
    }
    public void setCorporative(String corporative) {
        this.corporative = corporative;
    }

    @Column(name="Formato")
    public String getFormat() {
        return format;
    }
    public void setFormat(String format) {
        this.format = format;
    }


    @Column(name="Tipo")
    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }
    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    @Version
    @Column(name="Version")
    public Long getVersion() {
        return version;
    }
    public void setVersion(Long version) {
        this.version = version;
    }
}
```

My Cache definition inside persistence.xml looks like:

```
         <!-- Cache Configuration  -->
         <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true"/>
         <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true"/>
         <property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class" value="com.asbitec.server.cache.VBICacheRegionFactory"/>
         <property name="net.sf.ehcache.configurationResourceName" value="/vbi-cache-config.xml"/>
```

My Cache Factory looks like this:

```
public class VBICacheRegionFactory extends EhCacheRegionFactory {
    private static final EhCacheMessageLogger LOG = Logger.getMessageLogger(
            EhCacheMessageLogger.class,
            EhCacheRegionFactory.class.getName()
    );

    private static final String VBI_DATABASE_NAME = "com.areateclab.vbi.database.name";

    public VBICacheRegionFactory() {
        super();
    }

    public VBICacheRegionFactory(Properties prop) {
        super(prop);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Settings settings, Properties properties) throws CacheException {
        this.settings = settings;
        if ( manager != null ) {
            LOG.attemptToRestartAlreadyStartedEhCacheProvider();
            return;
        }

        try {
            String configurationResourceName = null;
            String databaseName = null;
            if ( properties != null ) {
                configurationResourceName = (String) properties.get( NET_SF_EHCACHE_CONFIGURATION_RESOURCE_NAME );
                databaseName = (String) properties.get(VBI_DATABASE_NAME);
            }
            if ( configurationResourceName == null || configurationResourceName.length() == 0 ) {
                final Configuration configuration = ConfigurationFactory.parseConfiguration();
                manager = new CacheManager( configuration );
            }
            else {
                final URL url = loadResource( configurationResourceName );
                final Configuration configuration = HibernateEhcacheUtils.loadAndCorrectConfiguration( url );
                if(databaseName!=null) {
                    configuration.setName(databaseName+"cacheManager");
                }
                manager = new CacheManager( configuration );
            }
            mbeanRegistrationHelper.registerMBean( manager, properties );
        }
        catch (net.sf.ehcache.CacheException e) {
            if ( e.getMessage().startsWith(
                    "Cannot parseConfiguration CacheManager. Attempt to create a new instance of " +
                            "CacheManager using the diskStorePath"
            ) ) {
                throw new CacheException(
                        "Attempt to restart an already started EhCacheRegionFactory. " +
                                "Use sessionFactory.close() between repeated calls to buildSessionFactory. " +
                                "Consider using SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory. Error from ehcache was: " + e.getMessage()
                );
            }
            else {
                throw new CacheException( e );
            }
        }
    }



}
```

I read similar questions around here and the web but I couldn't found any relation between the answers and my present use case.
I am not updating any other entity inside the transaction that the one I present here.
The only particular issue I could think of is that the GasStation class extends CatalogEntity which has other children that use READ_ONLY cache strategy, not sure if that is related.